# BroadcastReceiver "action.USER_PRESENT" is not called

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, screen, android-broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to register the device unlock event. I use the receiver with action = "android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT".

When the application is active - everything works. When I delete an application from the curtain of recently launched - does not work. And this problem is noticeable with API21 (on 4.4. - everything works). This is expected, because Google from API21 seriously engaged in optimizing the work of background applications, but how does this receiver work? Code of manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.appdroid.develop.receiverscreenlock">
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name=".ScreenReceiver">
        <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Class code:

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String TAG = "myLog";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG,"onReceive "+ intent.getAction());
    Toast.makeText(context,"screen unlock",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}}
```

Comment: Try to add <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

Comment: @John, this does not work

Answer (score 1):

Someone report that setting in manifest does not help, so try to sse this in your onCreate method:

```
receiver = new ScreenReceiver()
IntentFilter i=new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        i.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);               
        registerReceiver(receiver ,i);
```

You cannot receive this through components declared in manifests, only by explicitly registering for it with Context.registerReceiver() [source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SCREEN_ON), so I think you cannot receive if your app is killed.

However you can use service:

```
public static class UpdateService extends Service {

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            // register receiver that handles screen on and screen off logic
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
            filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
            BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new ScreenReceiver();
            registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
            boolean screenOn = intent.getBooleanExtra("screen_state", false);
            if (!screenOn) {
                // your code
            } else {
                // your code
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: This method only works when the application is active. If the application is turned off, the broadcast receiver does not work (

Comment: The only possibility maybe to use service which will listen.

Comment: Android will kill this service to optimize battery performance. I'm right?

Comment: It should prior to 6.0. In Marshmallow there is new Doze mode which will kill it if you haven't added it to Protected apps (Settings > Advanced Settings > Battery Manager > Protected apps)

Comment: What is the intent to call to go to this menu?

Comment: This feature is not available on all phones and you should better navigate to settings screen and ask user for this

Comment: If this function is not on all phones, then the service on some phones will be killed by the system?

Comment: Yes, because only trusted apps can run

Comment: But how to solve this problem for phones that do not have:Settings > Advanced Settings > Battery Manager > Protected apps

Comment: I think only if you will be added to trusted apps by google

Comment: I absolutely do not understand how to do it. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: No, but as I know only big companies like Facebook are considered

Comment: <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />use this one and wait after switch on wait for 2 more minutes